# PHP - get json data from url

Tags: php, json, url, openstreetmap

I'm trying to load json data from this url =
http://api.opencagedata.com/geocode/v1/json?query=48.84737%2C2.28605&pretty=1&no_annotations=1&no_dedupe=1&key=b61388b5a248b7cfcaa9579ed290485b

Using file_get_contents works with other json urls but this one is strange. It returns only "{" the first line. Strlen gives 1480 which is right.Substr(2,18) gives "documentation" which is right too. But still i can't echo the entire text. Maybe there's some way to read the text line by line and save it in another string ? The entire text is still fully loaded in the textfile
Here's the php code i tried

```
<?php
$url = file_get_contents("http://api.opencagedata.com/geocode/v1/json?query=48.84737%2C2.28605&pretty=1&no_annotations=1&no_dedupe=1&key=b61388b5a248b7cfcaa9579ed290485b");
$save = file_put_contents("filename.txt", $url);
echo $url;
?>
```

Also tried this function but still same.

```
function get_data($url) {
 $ch = curl_init();
 $timeout = 5;
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
 $data = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
 return $data;
}
```

Comment: It works as expected when I run it.  I get the full JSON response and it saves to file.  How are you calling your above code; via HTTP Server or CLI?

Comment: You don't need to read it line by line. JSON is allowed to have line breaks, they're ignored as whitespace when you decode it.

Comment: I'm calling from an android virutal device via HttpUrlConnection. When i parse other json and I echo the string. It shows the whole string. But why this one only shows the first line ? How can I get the "formatted" string if i try to json_decode ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get return value with json_decode.

```
function get_data($url) {
 $ch = curl_init();
 $timeout = 5;
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
 $data = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
 return json_decode($data,true);
}
```